# REST API URL best practice

Tags: api, rest, url

Let's say I have two models. `Project` and `Task`. A task is must belongs to a project.

Which of the following URL endpoints is best practice?

1. GET `https://api.myapp.com/projects/:project_id/tasks/:task_id`
2. GET `https://api.myapp.com/tasks/:task_id?project_id=:project_id`

For filtering result I always use query params but I wondering what **SHOULD** we do with required params?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the REST best practices, a resource member should be in the url. In your case this means:

> https://api.myapp.com/projects/:project_id/tasks/:task_id

Query parameters should be used as filters. For example to get all tasks whose name begins with "TEST"/

```
https://api.myapp.com/projects/:project_id/tasks/:task_id?nameStartsWith=TEST
```

---

You can read more about it in here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/resources.html
Download the PDF and take a look at page 14 - Resource naming.